# get android google history through python

Tags: python, android, browser-history

i have created a program that will display my current search history as you can see below

```
original_db_path = '\\Users\\djtal\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 2\\History'

# Specify the path for the backup database file
backup_db_path = '\\Users\\djtal\\documents\\folder1'

# Make a copy of the original database file
shutil.copyfile(original_db_path, backup_db_path)

con = sqlite3.connect("\\Users\\djtal\\documents\\folder1")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("select url, title, visit_count, last_visit_time from urls")
url = cur.fetchall()[-1]
```

All is good for getting google history from my computer, but i want to do the same thing but with my android phone. does anybody know what the file directory is on android?

i have tried the directory (com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox) but this cant be read. is search history stored somewhere else? is it because the file cannot be opened?